# How to solve installation problem of visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting an error while installing vscode. It is showing "An error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory". vscode is not installing becau[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONsU9.png)se of this problem. Can anyone solve this error?

Comment: is that you are trying to re install vs code or it's a fresh installation

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your attempts to resolve it

Comment: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.js  {error message : An error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory: MoveFile failed; code2. The system cannot find the file specified}

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important information

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue when installing VS code. It seems that it is a general issue happening for any software installation when any of files are quarantined by anti virus programs running during the installation. (Reference: https://forum.greenheartgames.com/t/move-file-failed-code-2-during-installation/6174 https://www.asap-utilities.com/faq-questions-answers-detail.php?m=334)

In my case, I just disabled the antivirus program temporarily during the installation and the issue get resolved during my next attempt of VS code installation.

Comment: Dude you are just great. Thanks for helping. Saved the day of my school junior